# How to convert Evaluate() to a string without truncation?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code...

```
Dim Formula As String  
Dim Output As String  

Formula = "IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(D3, SCALES!N:P, 2, FALSE)), CONCATENATE(""PY "", IF(LEFT(BM3,4) = ""PPY "", RIGHT(BM3,LEN(BM3)-4), BM3) / VLOOKUP(D3, SCALES!N:P, 3, FALSE)), IF(LEFT(M3) = ""PPY "", CONCATENATE(""PPY "", RIGHT(M3, LEN(M3) - 4) / VLOOKUP(D3, SCALES!N:P, 2, FALSE)), M3 / VLOOKUP(D3, SCALES!N:P, 2 FALSE)))"  

Output = CStr(Sheet1.Evaluate(Formula))
```

...results in `Output` equaling "Error 2015" when `Formula` is longer than 255 characters.

I can't recast `Output` as a Double for other reasons. So, how can I convert the results of that `Evaluate()` call to a string without the formula being truncated to 255 characters?

### ***Edit:***

When...
`Formula = "IF(ISBLANK(SCALES!L3),""PY ""&IF(LEFT(BM2,4)=""PPY "",RIGHT(BM2,LEN(BM2)-4),BM2)/VLOOKUP(D2,SCALES!K:M,3,FALSE),IF(LEFT(M2)=""PPY "",""PPY ""&RIGHT(M2,LEN(M2)-4)/VLOOKUP(D2,SCALES!K:M,2,FALSE)),M2/VLOOKUP(D2,SCALES!K:M,2,FALSE))"`
...and L3 is blank, BM2 is "40430", D2 is "TX", and M2 is "41197" I'm still getting an `Output` of "Error 2015".

Shortening the formulas did fix some of my errors, however this particular formula (which is 220 characters) is still giving me issues. Any ideas on this, now?

Comment: Can you paste here the exact formula that works in Excel?

Comment: The reason you still get an error is that your new formula contains 4 arguments for the first IF function; there should only be 3.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that and have figured it all out now. So as it stands I have no errors with any of my current formulas. My only follow up question would be: what if I have a formula that I can't compress down to 255 or fewer characters? Is there another way to do this that will help future-proof this issue?

Comment: Try option #2 from my answer below. For example, break out the Vlookups using `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`. It will require more lines of code, but will avoid the 255-character limit of the Evaluate method.

Comment: @RachelHettinger - For reasons beyond the scope of this question that doesn't quite work with my application, however it does solve the problem if I refactor a huge portion of my code so I marked your answer as correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact is that you've run up against a limitation in Excel--the Evaluate method only takes strings up to 255 characters. You have a few options:

1. Try removing all unnecessary spaces and use the & instead of the concatenate function. That might shorten your formula enough.
2. Break the formula up into pieces and use the WorksheetFunction method rather than the Evaluate method.
3. Put the formula into a cell on your worksheet, calculate it and retrieve the value.

Comment: So you're saying that it isn't the `CStr()` call that's truncating anything, it's `Evaluate()` itself that's doing it? Crap. I can cut this formula down to less than 255 characters but in the future I might have others that can't be kept within that limit. For reasons I won't bother get into here I kind of need to do this in this manner, is there no other way of executing a cell formula in VBA?

Comment: I edited my original post with new information. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Yeah, I just started error checking the formula and realized I'm a bonehead. This is likely now just a problem with my syntax.

Comment: Another thing that saved me a lot of characters was to move Worksheet references outside the string. I was using something like `Evaluate("somesheet!$a$1+somesheet!$a$2")` and turned it into `Worksheets("somesheet").Evaluate("$a$1 + $a$2")`. This was helpful because all my references were to the same sheet, and there were lots of them!